# Continuously getting duplicate push notifications for React native FCM

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I keep on getting same Push Notification for single trigger from server.

I am using [react-native-fcm(v13).x](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) for implementing PN on android. I am facing this issue on only some android devices(One Plus 5 and Samsung s5).

I have ensured following things :

- I am not registering listener multiple times
- I have tried moving the code to another component
- There is no other receiver in AndroidMenifest file
- The server is sending a single notification for a single request from the app

React-native - 0.48.4

The issue occurs in both foreground and background modes.

Comment: _Getting too many push notification for React native FCM_ Can you please specify your problem? What does _too many_ mean?

Comment: I think react-native-firebase has better support for doing push notifications via FCM.

Comment: I just want to use Messaging feature of Firebase. react-native-firebase has like all the features of firebase.

Comment: i used @react-native-firebase/messaging for push-notification & get 3 continuously notification. can anyone help me. 
react-native 0.61.5
@react-native-firebase/messaging ^7.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got fixed. Unsure of the cause and resolution. Here is the combination which worked for me :

a) Removed dexOptions from build.gradle

b) Downgraded the react-native-fcm to v8.0.1 from 10.0.3 .

c) Changed version code

Answer (score 0):

Please check settings.gradle file

My issues:- I was calling this twice

include ':react-native-fcm'
project(':react-native-fcm').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fcm/android')

check this one

if this doesn't work please redo the linking manually

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem got solved. Solution mentioned below worked for me.